# Cakephp Fatal error rendering issue

Tags: cakephp

I'm using Cakephp version 2.2.4 and it is unable to render Fatal error messages (It shows weird characters).
When i remove the line 'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleError' from core file, PHP displays the Fatal error correctly.

[Here is a link to screenshot of what i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU7rI.png)

Here's the content of my core file (Error related):
    Configure::write('debug', 2);

```
Configure::write('Exception', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleException',
    'renderer' => 'ExceptionRenderer',
    'log' => true
));
Configure::write('Error', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleError',
     'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT,
    'trace' => true
));
```

Thanks

Comment: Give us some code, Aria - You big tease.

Comment: lol Happy, this does not happen on any particular controller or model,  If the Error Handler is set to Cake's, it happens anywhere with a Fatal error in code.

Comment: Can you show us exactly what you have in your core file to start? What do you have 'debug' set to in the file?

Answer (score 0):

Update to the recently released CakePHP version 2.2.5, which apparently fixed some problems in ExceptionHandler.

Answer (score -1):

I just checked and found that I was referencing a model I had not loaded. Loading the model (Actually referencing it through the current model) solved the problem for me.